# Show that $f$ is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$

Tags: derivatives

Let $f$ be a function such that for all $a,b$ on $(0,+∞)$, we have $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b), f(1)=0$, and  $ f'(1)=1$

Show that f is continuous on $(0,+∞)$

Here's what I thought. I should prove either that $f$ is differentiable  on $(0,+\infty)$ or that $\lim_\limits{x\to a}=f(a)$ on $(0,+\infty)$. But I can't figure out how to get there. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I can bet that the second question will be :  prove that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,+\infty)$ so here is the solution : $f(x+h)-f(x)=f((x+h)/x)$ as $(x+h)/x\to1$ when $h\to0$ and as $f'(1)=1$, $f(x)\sim f'(1)x$ when $x\to1$ you finally have that $f'(x)=1/x$ and that $f(x)=\ln(x)$ because $f(1)=0$

Answer (score 3):

Let $a \in (0,\infty)$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. Notice that for all $x$, $f(x) = f(x/a) + f(a)$.

As $f$ is continuous at $1$, $\exists \ \delta > 0$, $|u-1| < \delta$ gives $|f(u) - f(1)| < \epsilon $

Now let $x \in (0,\infty)$.

$$|x - a| < a \delta \implies |x/a - 1| < \delta \implies  |f(x/a) - f(1)| < \epsilon \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon $$

Answer (score 1):

f is continuous at the point $x=1$ because $f'(1)$ exists.
Knowing that, lets take a b such that $b\to1$ in the equality $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$ and you got that f is continuous in a

Comment: @JohnMa, if you don't know that f is continuous in 1, how could you use the fact that $f(1)=0$